# ng-submit not working in angular js

Tags: php, angularjs

In my below code only angular validation is working. When I click on login button, then no angular script works. Can some body help me? Where is my mistake?

```
   <div class=" col-sm-6">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default  center-blocks btn-save" ng-disabled="adminForm.$invalid" id="btn-save">Login</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default center-blocks btn-save" ng-disabled="adminForm.$invalid" id="btn-save">Login</button>
```

you need to  button type to submit type.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your button type as `type="submit"`. Currently it is `type="button"` which would not submit a form

Also make sure you have `ng-sumbit="submit()"` on your form level element.